# Тестирование на всех устройствах

Tags: android

Погуглив, я ничего не нашел по этому поводу. Эмуляторов всяких ноу нэйм или китайских устройств нет.

Хотел спросить как вы тестируете свои приложение на устройствах и есть ли сервисы по тестированию приложения на всех устройствах?

Answer (score 1):

Вообще то есть специализированные компании, которые в том числе тестируют на физических устройствах. Есть в Москве несколько таких, сам не обращался, но знаю что люди обращались к ним - говорили всякое и хорошее и не очень. Ну тестирование (хотя бы поверхностное) на 10-20 устройствах они вам точно обеспечат.

Чтобы не обвинили меня в скрытой рекламе вбейте в Yandex/Google что-то типа:

> Тестирование мобильных приложений на Android

или

> Mobile testing services Android

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю у многих данный вопрос возникает в процессе написания приложения на мобильные устройства. Самому тестировать на куче устройств мне кажется времени не хватит охватить все возможные девайсы. Но ведь как-то тестировать нужно)) Первый и самый простой вариант, который вы обойти ну никак не сможете - при выгрузке в Google Play вы проходите тестирование на 12 ( лично у меня так) устройствах, не физических понятное дело, но тем не менее. Ваша программа будет протестирована по всем параметрам, которые Google посчитает нужным. Так же есть вариант, использовать свои тесты при тестировании гугл - вы пишите на своем эмуляторе так называемый robo-test и выгружаете его в Google Play console а дальше робот гугла по тому что вы написали один раз тестирует все 12 устройств. Это не значит что вам нужно будет ручками что-то писать, это просто журнал ваших действий. Записывается полностью все что вы делаете. Дальше после того как вы прошли проверку на гугловских эмуляторах вы можете создать закрытое тестирование и подвязать до 100 тестировщиков. Люди будут тестировать ваше приложение а вы будете получать фидбек. Так же есть насколько я помню возможность тестировать в Firebase, если не знаете что и как там делается то в сети куча информации. Еще один вариант - найти какой-то онлайн сервис и там прогнать ваше приложение. Самый глупый наверное вариант - давать инсталлер друзьям коллегам и просить протестровать, но за неимением ничего другого это тоже вариант.

Помните всех багов вы не сможете найти и починить, полюбому будут какие-то косяки. Вопрос только в том как минимизировать кол-во этих косяков при релизе. Гугловское тестирование вам в этом постарается помочь в полной мере.